# How to parse multiple cookies values from Set-Cookie (contains commas and semicolons)

Tags: regex

I'm actually using:

```
(.*?)=(.*?);
```

But it's not parsing properly due to the commas that it contains.
You can test patterns here > http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
Here's the cookies string:

```
Set-Cookie: PAGE_VIS=A|186.213.98.144|1381089446.485193|; domain=PAGE; path=/; expires=Mon, 07-Oct-2013 06:00:00 GMT,CSASF=;Version=1;Domain=PAGE;Path=/;Max-Age=7776000,CSAPAGES=ekpEOWluWTZSMXpDSWRMMm8wWWZ3UT09|5749|kNm6h4hlOB4SwLFg2gOIMXXpmTXDD5tnvB/dJ7AS3mUqUiLtpHLxzsWjfKsI1rcq6fp/DKre3QHAZHPQi968iw==;Version=1;Domain=PAGE;Path=/;Max-Age=7776000;HttpOnly,NAM_LOGIN_DEFAULT=user;Version=1;Domain=PAGE;Path=/;Max-Age=129600,UPL09=2-25|39|54|56|58|90|91|105|106|156|182|212|218|219|242|245|248|284|285|480|1222;Version=1;Domain=PAGE;Path=/;Max-Age=2592000,PAGE_OTR=;Version=1;Domain=PAGE;Path=/;Max-Age=2592000,CAUBR01=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;Version=1;Domain=PAGE;Path=/
```

Comment: What's the problem with the commas?  This appears to work

Comment: Max-Age is merged with UPL09, it happens with another ones that has comma on it too, I'm using this pattern to split name and value from the cookie.

Comment: So you are basically wanting to split on commas and semi-colons instead of just semi-colons? But how would you expect this to work? It seems there are valid cases where a comma isn't meant to split... like "Mon, 07-..."

Comment: Yes, if I used only semicolons,it would return merged values, the date is really a problem indeed :(

Comment: I don't think you are going to be able to use a single regex to parse all of those cookies in a single operation. For one thing, commas separate cookies, but the `expires` attribute of a cookie also has a comma in it, so a single regex would not know how to differentiate that so you have to use separate logic to handle it. Also, the semicolon-delimited values are attributes of a single cookie, they are not separate cookies of their own. And lastly, RFC 6265 makes it illegal to have multiple cookies in a single `Set-Cookie` header anyway. They need their own individual `Set-Cookie` headers now.

Comment: @AndréIkvmo, I've spotted something that might work for your data as long as it stays fairly consistent and updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: I've got two right answers and have to choose one, I don't know which one should I choose, also I would like to thank everyone who helped me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this might work for you:

```
(.*?)=(.*?)($|;|,(?! ))
```

the last part is saying:
`$` end of string `|` or ...
`;` semi-colon `|` or  ...
`,(?! )` comma not followed by a space

[**result**](http://regexr.com?36krd)

The best thing would be to actually be consistent with your separators (use semi-colons all the time)... and this seems to be kinda hinky but I think it will work for your situation as all the commas you don't want to split at seem to be followed by a space from what I can tell... (as long as your data doesn't change to be like "foo=bar,baz; blah=foo").

Comment: That also worked, how do I choose just one answer if there's two right? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @AndréIkvmo Ah... you can pick only one, unfortunately :(

Comment: @AndréIkvmo, make sure your last key/value pair is matched at the end of the string.

Comment: Very compact, I like that. Unfortunately this one fails at the string `Name1=Value1,Name2=Value2;` too... If there is a way to spot any `=` before the next `;` I think that would fix this issue.

Comment: @Broxzier, actually there wouldn't be a problem with that string as it is a comma not followed by a space so it would end the match (see [**here**](http://regexr.com?36krg)). The problem is as I mentioned in my answer, commas not followed by a space that he won't want to split on. As for your suggestion, it might work, but there are also cases you could come up with that would cause problems with as well. The format of the test string is certainly not ideal.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using a negative lookahead:

```
(.*?)=(.*?)(?:;|,(?!\s))
```

The second part of the match will end at a comma which is not followed by a space, and the only comma followed by a space seems to be in the date, while it is being used as separator everywhere else.

Answer (score 4):

The following will split at both a `,` and a `;`, however, I think **you shouldn't split at commas**! This regex will also match the last entry in the string, since this one is missing a `;`.

> *So you are basically wanting to split on commas and semi-colons instead of just semi-colons? But how would you expect this to work? It seems there are valid cases where a comma isn't meant to split... like "Mon, 07-..."* –  smerny

```
(.*?)=((.*?)[;,]|.*$)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, your answer is really complete, but it's not parsing "expires" value properly, if I do not split at commas the other values will merge with them like "Name1=Value1,Name2=Value2;"

Comment: @AndréIkvmo Indeed, and that's why you shouldn't split at commas. :)